# Using prerender.io with ReactJS for SEO

Tags: seo, reactjs, prerender, react-router

I've realized that my ReactJS application using react-router does not have any external links. Search engines do not recognize that the site has a lot of linked content. Prerender.io seems like a good solution to this, but I cannot get it to work for my ReactJS application.

Can prerender.io be used with ReactJS? If not, is there another good way to improve SEO for my site without doing all the rendering server-side?

EDIT: Upon further digging, I realized that the issue here is that react-router uses a "#" by default, and not a "#!". Is it possible to make react-router work with a "#!"?

Comment: Curious, I'm not a react developer, but I can see [react-spa.herokuapp.com](http://react-spa.herokuapp.com/discussions) working with html5mode react-routing

Comment: @ritmatter Well we also have faced this issue while we are working on ReactJs application which needs SEO optimization as well. Please checkout our reactjs boiler plate using which we can create SEO freindly web apps. https://github.com/Atyantik/react-pwa/ .

Answer (score 2):

Prerender appears to expect real urls, because otherwise you can't serve the cached html to normal people (the hash isn't sent to the server).

When setting up react-router ensure it's using the history mode:

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
```

In your server you'll need to ensure that all routes that don't match a static file are served by either sending index.html, or using prerender.

You can search for 'send all requests to index.html {insert server name here}' to find details on this.

---

It seems that by default prerender only applies in certain situations.  Here's an example if you're using the express.js middleware in node.js:

```
require('prerender-node').shouldShowPrerenderedPage = function(){ return true }
```

You should be able to figure out similar modifications for other middleware (it'll require a fork in less flexible languages).

Comment: I tried this, but it still didn't work. Prerender apparently has to work with a hashbang, instead of a hash, but I also couldn't get it to work that way.

Comment: @ritmatter, I updated my answer.  Also, please read their documentation... they explicitly recommend not using `#!` urls.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll look into that. The recommendation to use a "#!" in the url came in a reply from support@prerender.io. Is it possible that there are two different strategies?

Comment: I don't know, but it's impossible to server side render a url with `#!` in it, except to a subset of bots.  Anything after the `#` isn't sent to the server.

Comment: Sorry I missed this. It's recommended to use html5 push state over the `#!`. With html5 push state, you use the <meta name="fragment" content="!"> tag in the <head> and crawlers will request the URL with  `?_escaped_fragment_=` at the end of the URL. If you use the `#!` then crawlers will replace the `#!` with `?_escaped_fragment_=`. That's how we detect the crawlers. See here for more documentation: https://prerender.io/documentation/test-it